# Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction removing slash in Name parameter

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to dynamically find the build numbers of all the apps in one of my environments. In my Production environment there are standard apps:

> Microsoft.Web/sites/sitenamewebjob05

and then there are my staging slots:

> Microsoft.Web/sites/sitenamewebjob05/slots/staging

I have a function that examines each name to determine weather it need to be passes with the "/staging" or not.

```
Function Get-ResourceTypeAndName($SiteName, $Slot)
{
    $ResourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    $ResourceName = $SiteName
    #$slash = '(?=//)'
    if ($Slot -ne $null -and $Slot -like "staging") 
    {
        $ResourceType = "$($ResourceType)/slots"
        $ResourceName = "$($ResourceName)/staging"
    }
    else 
    {
        $ResourceType = "$($ResourceType)/config"
        $ResourceName = $SiteName
    }

    $ResourceType, $ResourceName
}
```

then $ResourceType and $ResourceName are passed to my Invoke-AzureRmResourceaction

```
$siteProperties = (Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
            -ResourceType $ResourceType `
            -Name "$ResourceName/appsettings" `
            -ApiVersion $ApiVersion `
            -Action list `
            -Force).Properties
```

Whenever I attempt to run this i get this error: 
[image]
the specific part I am trying to rectify is the fact that it removes my slash:

[image]

I am unsure what exactly is the problem here as I have tried different forms of concatenation.

Comment: did you try debugging it? does it work if you put in proper values manually?

Answer (score 0):

This could be better achieved with [`Get-AzureRmWebSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebappslot) and [`Get-AzureRmWebApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebapp).